# Is it possible to subtract 6hrs from DateDiff?

Tags: sql, ms-access, datediff

I am using the access query below to do some calculations. Because the server is located in Europe but the users of the application are in the US, there is a difference of 6 hours. In the command below, can I some how accommodate for this? So that when running the command it does the datediff minus 6 hours somehow?

```
Days Waiting : IIf([Datereceivedunit] Is Null,0,IIf([QuoteFrom] Is Null,DateDiff("d",[Datereceivedunit],Date())-(DateDiff("ww",[Datereceivedunit],Date())*2),0))
```

Comment: As a general practice, but especially if system components are located in multiple timezones, you should always store UTC datetimes in a database, and only convert to local time for display in user interfaces as required. This also solves daylight savings time issues as well.

Comment: Where in the query would I put the dateadd -6 hours?

Comment: Hint:  `"h"` instead of `"d"`.

Comment: This query returns days so changing to 'h" would make the query wrong?

Comment: If `[Datereceivedunit]` and `[QuoteFrom]` don't contain a time part, subtracting 6 hours (from which?) will just add or subtract zero or one day to/from the current result.

If you add or subtract 6 hours from the current day difference, this will always be shifted by 6 hours.

Neither result seems appropriate, so you need to supply some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateAdd("h", 6, YourFieldName)`

Comment: This code will achieve the 6 hour request, but if you could provide an example of what you are trying to achieve, and tell me what is happening. I could better tell you what your code needs to look like.